# Having issues making Web Layout with both fixed and relative positions

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a site that scales properly based on browser size. I'm aware that usually requires to keep all width and heights set to 100%, however I have no clue how to set it when there's a minimum-height and minimum height for the header and footer. A school logo will be in the header which is unreadable when too small, and a google calendar in the sidebar.

What I'd like to do is set it up so that the header and subheader (dark blue and dark grey bars) are set to be a fixed position. The sidebar (black bar) set to fixed, as well as the footer (light grey). The content section (white box) I'd like to be the only scrollable section that contains all of the news and updates. No matter how I set it up something is always moving inappropriately.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>
        Website Layout Test
    </title>        
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" media="screen">     
</head>

<body>
    <div id="header-container">
        <div id="header"></div>
        <div id="sub-header"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="content-container">
        <div id="content"></div>
        <div id="sidebar"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

and the css

```
#header-container{
    width:100%;
    height:96px;
    position:relative;
}
#header{
    width:100%;
    background-color:#013066;
    height:60px;
    position:fixed;
}
#sub-header{
    width:100%;
    background-color:grey;
    margin-top:60px;
    height:36px;
    position:fixed;
}
#content-container{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
    padding-bottom:55px;
    background-color:pink;
}
#content{
    background-color:white;
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
}
#sidebar{
    width:315px;
    height:100%;
    background-color:black;
    position:fixed;
    right:0px;
}
#footer{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    height:40px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#f6f6f6;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add z-index:10 to #header-container....and all your problems will be solved!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>
    Website Layout Test
</title>        


<style>
    #header-container{
width:100%;
height:96px;
position:relative;
  z-index: 10;
}
#header{
width:100%;
background-color:#013066;
height:60px;
position:fixed;
 }
#sub-header{
width:100%;
background-color:grey;
margin-top:60px;
height:36px;
position:fixed;
}
#content-container{
width:100%;
height:1021px;
position:relative;
padding-bottom:55px;

}
#content{
background-color:white;
float:left;
height:100%;
width:100%;
position:relative;
border: 10px solid red;
}
#sidebar{
width:315px;
height:100%;
background-color:black;
position:fixed;
right:0px;
}
#footer{
position:fixed;
bottom:0px;
height:40px;
width:100%;
background-color:#f6f6f6;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="header-container">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="sub-header"></div>
</div>

<div id="content-container">
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="sidebar"></div>
</div>

<div id="footer"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks that surprisingly worked perfectly! I'm guessing that had to do with the content-container scrolling up over the header-container rather than the latter just scrolling up with.

Comment: when two elements in html overlap then one gets hidden under the other depending upon the z-index of the element. since i have set the z-index of the headcontainer to 10, it will always be above the contentconatiner. Well 10 is a random value which i have used. u can use any other higher value. The element with the highest z-index stays at top.GOOD LUCK!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need all the position: relative; stuff in there if you're using floats. Another thing you can do is add "overflow: auto" to the content div and do "overflow: hidden" on the others. Have you looked into bootstrap. This is very easy if you're using bootstrap. Check out: http://getbootstrap.com/ , it makes this type of stuff very very easy.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but there's a lot more I'll need to do on top of this that I don't know will be compatible with bootstrap and don't have the time currently to find out if it does.